# TestNG @Test can have a testID?

Tags: testng

I'm trying to adapt testrail api.
I want to set a integer testID value for a @Test and get the value at iTestListener.

In testNG, is there a way to specify a test id for each @Test?

I tried getTestName, but it seems that it's not designed to use this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Test annotation is the best way to achieve this and there are various guides online to do it.

Simply put you'd create a new annotation class

e.g.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface TestParameters {
    String[] testRailId() default "";
}
```

Then within your test put the test / case ID (without the preceding T or C, as the testrail API doesn't accept them).

```
@Test(priority = 0, description = "Some description")
@TestParameters(testRailId= {"1234"})
public void My_Test(){
   //do something
   }
```

Then in the listener:

```
String[] testID;
IClass obj = iTestResult.getTestClass();
Class<?> newobj = obj.getRealClass();
Method testMethod = null;
testMethod = newobj.getMethod(iTestResult.getMethod().getMethodName());

if (testMethod.isAnnotationPresent(TestParameters.class)) {
   TestParameters useAsTestName = testMethod.getAnnotation(TestParameters.class);
   // Get the TestCase ID for Test Rail
   testID = (useAsTestName.testRailId());
   // Do something with the testID
   }
```

There are other ways to do it, but they usually start to fall over when you're using TestNG's parallel testing abilities.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this way.

Comment: Yup, This is pure gold to me. Thank you! It is beautifully working

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. I think I found a way.
It looks a little bit wierd, but it works.
add ITestContext parameter at the test method, and set a value at the context.

```
@Test()
public void sample(ITestContext context){
context.setAttribute("testId", 11111);
//Your test
assertEquals(true, true);
}
```

At the on success or fail method, get context from result.

```
@Override
public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result){
ITestContext context = result.getTestContext();
System.out.prinln(context.getAttribute("testId")); // you can get the attribute!
}
```

Do some other things in the @Test method seems weird. But it works for now.

Comment: I think specifying a value at the parameter of @Test annotation is the best. But I don't know how to do it.